# Add global basename/context to React and npm settings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I have a problem with urls, I need to run my application not from localhost:8081, but from localhost:8081/admin, so all pages shows me 404, which have /...., anyway main page also doesn't work good, in index.html I have also  tag, example of file.

```
<link href="../public/css_admin/fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Webpack configuration

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        publicPath: '/admin/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx']
    },
    .....
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8081
    },
    externals: {
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: '..../rest/v1'
        })
    }
}
```

App route

```
render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}  basename="admin">
                <div>                    
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={MainIndexPage} refresh={false} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/staff" component={StaffPage}  refresh={false}  />
                        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />                   
                    </Switch>
                </div>
             </Router>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm a beginner. basename="admin" or basename="/admin".

Answer (score 0):

So please add basename to the history,

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({basename: '/admin'});
```

Also change

```
 filename: 'bundle.js' -> filename: 'app-[hash].js'
```